# In Angular2, how to make <app-root> 100% height

Tags: css, angular

I am using Angular2 and I want to set the height of `<app-root>` to 100% of `<body>`.

Currently I have:

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

and in CSS file I've set:

```
app-root {
  height: 100%;
}
```

but it seems nothing changed.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: What issue you are facing due to this any description???

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In the component css use the :host selector

```
:host {
    height: 100%
}
```

Comment: This is the correct way of styling a component https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host

Comment: Right, as it mentions that is the way to style the component host, and app-root is the bootstrapped component, so it does not violate encapsulation

Comment: Awesome. Works for me.

Comment: This should be the acepted answer.

Answer (score 25):

Just set `display` property to `block`:

```
app-root {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

All custom elements are created as `inline` so you cannot manipulate their dimensions. You need to make them block elements.

Comment: Doesn't work. In the dev tool, I can see the height of the element is 100% but still seems like approx 70%.

Comment: make a screenshot and post a link, you're probably looking at the page height, not the body

Comment: I guess the height of app-root just contains the inner components

Comment: _and in css file I set_ - what css file? how's it loaded?

Comment: I'm using Angular-cli, I put the code in styles.css and it is loaded in <head>

Comment: can you create a plunker? and what if you set height to `1000px` to the body, will they match?

Comment: Interesting. I removed the <app-root> and just put a <div> in <body> with 100% height. It displayed 0. Seems the height only conforms to the content while the width works.

Comment: well, my solution is correct, you have to learn more about css [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) vs [inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) elements. if you have more questions, create a plunker please. it's hard to understand what's going on in your code

Comment: Ok I will have a look and plunker, new to front end :P

Answer (score 20):

Some time has passed, now I have had the problem. This is the solution that I am applying

In your `app.component.css` or desired component use this style

```css
:host {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0; 
  border: solid 3px yellow; /* for debugging purposes */
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer on this page that seems to work, just remember to set `box-sizing: border-box;` so that that 3px border doesn't push the vertical past 100% and cause the scrollbar to appear.

Comment: Thank you very much! This made my day! Not only a day, but a week! It works like a charm!

Comment: Does not work if you have a vertical scroll

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it would be combining @ackuser and @LookForAngular answers with `flex`, which is now the standard. This way, in the root `styles.scss` of the app we could have something like:

```
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}
```

And then, in `app.component.scss`:

```
:host {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using simple javascript. On page load (or in your appComponent) you can set the height of app-root to be equal to window.innerHeight. So it will always take the height of your window.

Comment: Doesn't work. In the dev tool, I can see the height of the element is 100% but still seems like approx 70%.

Answer (score 0):

do this in your main style.css

```
  html, body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
  }
```

setting height to 100% on all your elements including 'app-root' should now work

Answer (score 0):

In your style.(s)css

```
app-root {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are struggling with it in Angular 16, none of those answers helped me to set the height of  to 100% because I had scrollable content, and when I scroll down,  does not follow.

So, at styles.css:

```
html, body, app-root {
    min-height: 100vh;
}

app-root {
   display: grid;
}
```

Setting app-root with **display: block** didn't worked for me. I really don't know why **display: grid** worked.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is the same as mine then it's probably related to cdk-describedby-message-container on the page.  You need to make sure that the mat.core mixin is included:

[How to include custom material themes into components without duplicating mixins: mat-core and angular-material-theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53007605/how-to-include-custom-material-themes-into-components-without-duplicating-mixins)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).