# How to include custom material themes into components without duplicating mixins: mat-core and angular-material-theme

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, themes

I found a very helpful explanation about how to apply material theme color schemes/palettes for other non-material-components [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46760306/get-material-2-theme-color-scheme-palette-for-other-elements).

Before I read this, I thought of something similar but couldn't imagine how to consider the recommendation from [Theming your Angular Material app](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#defining-a-custom-theme), if I don't want to have only global themes:

> Your custom theme file should not be imported into other SCSS files. This will duplicate styles in your CSS output. If you want to consume your theme definition object (e.g., $candy-app-theme) in other SCSS files, then the definition of the theme object should be broken into its own file, separate from the inclusion of the mat-core and angular-material-theme mixins.

I wonder if this recommendation means that only global style sheets/ themes should be used? Otherwise I cannot imagine how to import the scss-theme into a component's scss-file without violating the above recommendation.

I am new to Sass and maybe missing something here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I came across the same problem, some of the discussion can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1786), and an insighful blog dealing with the issue [here](https://blog.devintent.com/why-are-angular-material-styles-being-duplicated-in-my-project-68e2626432c9).

Point is that - as the theming guide correctly states - you should never import mixins `@include mat-core()` and `@include angular-material-theme($your-theme)` more than once in your entire project. But when you're working with SASS in your components, you often do want to refer to your theme variables and mat-color palette. It's tempting to import your entire theme into the component SASS, accidentally duplicating the material mixins.

The solution I ended up with I think is the one the theming guide describes

> the definition of the theme object should be broken into its own file, separate from the inclusion of the mat-core and angular-material-theme mixins

but since it was initially unclear to me how to do it, here's a step by step for anyone stuck with the same:

1. create a `assets/styles/partials` folder containing SASS partials

My folder looks like this:

```
assets/styles/partials/
  _palette.scss     // custom material palettes
  _scaffolding.scss // general mixins
  _theme.scss       // <-- our theme definition
  _variables.scss   // global variables like fonts and colors
```

The `_theme` partial contains the following:

```
// assets/styles/partials/_theme.scss
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@import 'variables';
@import 'scaffolding';
@import 'palette';

$my-primary: mat-palette($mat-primary);
$my-accent: mat-palette($mat-accent);
$my-warn: mat-palette($mat-warn);

$my-theme: mat-light-theme($my-primary, $my-accent);
```

That's it. Do *not* include the material mixins `mat-core` and `angular-material-theme` in this file.

2. create a global theme file `assets/styles/my-theme.scss`. It contains just three lines:

```
// assets/styles/my-theme.scss
@import 'partials/theme';                    // our actual theme definition
@include mat-core();                         // the required mat-core mixin
@include angular-material-theme($my-theme);  // the declaration of our custom material theme
```

By doing this we have separated our theme partial, including all our custome palette, scaffolding and variables, from the file that includes mat-core and our custom material theme.

3. In Angular.json, declare your my-theme file as global under styles

```
"styles": [ "src/assets/styles/my-theme.scss" ]
```

With this, our app uses our custom material theme throughout, but because the theme *definition* (in the `theme` partial) is separate from the inclusion of material mixins (in `my-theme`), we can safely include our `theme` partial into any component without duplicating any css.

Optionally, you can simplify the import of our theme partial by adding the partials path to the stylePreprocessorOptions in Angular.json:

```
"build": {
  (...)
  "options": {
    (...)
    "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
      "includePaths": [
        "src/assets/styles/partials"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Simply `@import 'theme'` in any component scss file and we have access to all our variables and the material theming functions such as mat-color :)

Comment: Thank you this is a very helpful and detailed explanation.

Comment: Finally a complete example. Thank you!

Comment: Finally an easy-to-follow guide to theming. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should have this right now :

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

$candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$candy-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);
$candy-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);

$candy-app-theme: mat-light-theme($candy-app-primary, $candy-app-accent, $candy-app-warn);

@include angular-material-theme($candy-app-theme);
```

But you should aim for that :

```
// First file variables.scss
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

$candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$candy-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);
$candy-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);
```

```
// Second file
@import 'src/variables';

$candy-app-theme: mat-light-theme($candy-app-primary, $candy-app-accent, $candy-app-warn);
@include angular-material-theme($candy-app-theme);
```

That's how I understood it.

Comment: Yeah that's always a pain in the a** ... You have to start from the `index.html` file and make a relative path out of it. For instance, if you put both files in the same folder, which is `src`, this would be `./variables`. I wrote `@src/variables` because I configured my own project to accept `src` as a starting path, but I could not tell you how, it's been too long ... So use a relative path !

Comment: @trichetiche wouldn't that import (`@import *src/variables`) include `mat-core()` multiple times?

Comment: Ok, in that case it is also duplicated. Maybe I am pedantic here. Seems, it's not possible to avoid duplicated including of `mat-core()`.

Comment: It shouldn't. Have you imported the second file twice ? Or declared it as an asset ?