# HTML/CSS: Background image is always relative to paragraph

Tags: html, css, angular

I am creating a test website with Angular, just to learn some things. First I put everything into the index.html, and this is the look I came up with:

[image]

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Reiche Freunde</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <a href="http://google.com">
    <p style="text-align: center; margin-top: 15%;"><img src="assets/Mony.gif" /></p>
  </a>
</body>
</html>
```

I then copied this html code and entered it into the app.component.html. Back in the index.html, I changed

```
<body style="background-image: url('assets/geld.jpg');">
  <a href="http://google.com">
  <p style="text-align: center; margin-top: 15%;"><img src="assets/Mony.gif" /></p>
  </a>
</body>
```

to

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

But then my Site started to look like this:

[image]

Where did I make the error? My app.component.css is empty, so there is nothing able to change the look of that background. I can't see any connection between the paragraph and the body itself, but the background is still relative to my dollar bill. When I put this into the app.component.css:

```
body {
  position: absolute;
}
```

,then i get this:

[image]

I'm just a starter in html/css, but all the tutorials about background images changed nothing for me

Comment: Looks like the background was on the `<body>` tag and after the change it isn't anymore

Comment: you can check the height of the app root https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45096456/in-angular2-how-to-make-app-root-100-height

Comment: Whenever possible, apply “screen-filling” background images to `html`, instead of `body`.  _“I'm just a starter in html/css”_ - then I would really focus on those first, before you start working with higher level complexity frameworks like Angular, tbh.

Comment: I have to use it at Work, even I know only some basics. idk why, but I can't just "focus on those first"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have two body tags, according to your answer ofc :)

One here (`index.html`) and second in `app.component.html`:

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

You can probably keep body into `app.component.html`, but you should remove it from index.html. And apply `display: block; height: 100%` for app-root, I suppose.

Comment: Oh, right, I see now, the <app-root> basically just moves another html page inside the index.html body, so the page doesn't need to reload, just the content changes